# Stop words are not being removed using python

Tags: python, nlp, stop-words

I am trying to remove stop words from the list of tokens I have. But, it seems like the words are not removed. What would be the problem? Thanks.

Tried:

```
Trans = []
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        file = myfile.read()
            #start readin from the start of the charecter
        myfile.seek(0)
        for row in myfile:
            split = row.split()
            Trans.append(split)
        myfile.close()


    stop_words = list(get_stop_words('en'))         
    nltk_words = list(stopwords.words('english')) 
    stop_words.extend(nltk_words)

    output = [w for w in Trans if not w in stop_words]


    Input: 

    [['Apparent',
      'magnitude',
      'is',
      'a',
      'measure',
      'of',
      'the',
      'brightness',
      'of',
      'a',
      'star',
      'or',
      'other']]

    output:

    It returns the same words as input.
```

Comment: This is probably to do with the double braces around your input. The first and only element of `Trans` is a list of words, so the condition in your list comprehension passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `Trans.append(split)` should be `Trans.extend(split)` because split returns a list.

Answer (score 1):

As the input contain list of list you need to traverse once the outer list and the inner list element after that you can get correct output using

```
output = [j for w in Trans for j in w if j not in stop_words]
```

Answer (score 1):

For more readability create a function. ex:

```
def drop_stopwords(row):
    stop_words = set(stopwords.words('en'))
    return [word for word in row if word not in stop_words and word not in list(string.punctuation)]
```

and `with open()` does not need a `close()`
and create a list of strings (sentences) and apply the function. ex:

```
Trans = Trans.map(str).apply(drop_stopwords)
```

This will be applied to each sentence...
You can add other functions for lemmitize, etc. Here there is a very clear example (code):
https://github.com/SamLevinSE/job_recommender_with_NLP/blob/master/job_recommender_data_mining_JOBS.ipynb